# Explain the meaning of projection of vector x onto $U^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra

What exactly does $proj_{U^\perp}(x)$ mean?

I know what  $proj_{U}(x)$ is, but I'm not sure how to interpret the projection of x onto the orthogonal complement, $U^\perp$.

Comment: The norm of this projection is the distance from $x$ to $U$.

Comment: It is just $x - \mathrm{proj}_U(x)$.

Comment: You say you know what the projection of a vector $x$ onto a subspace $U$ is; the orthogonal complement is just another subspace so the idea is exactly the same.